# how to differently write this part of the code?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class something {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int kvadratek, a, b;
        a = sc.nextInt();
        b = sc.nextInt();


        --a;
        --b;


        if(a>b) {

            kvadratek=b;
            b=a;
            a=kvadratek;

            System.out.println((a*(a+1)*(2*a+1)/6-((a+1)*a/2)*(a+b)+(a+1)*a*b));
        }


        else {

            System.out.println(a*(a+1)*(2*a+1)/6-((a+1)*a/2)*(a+b)+(a+1)*a*b);
        } 
    }
}
```

i am new to java coding and i have a question if i can write this part

```
kvadratek=b;
b=a;
a=kvadratek;
```

differently so that it will give me the same result as the else part. Is it possible to do it with if, while sentences? I actually don't need the else part of the code if I insert

```
kvadratek=b; 
b=a; 
a=kvadratek;
```

but is there a way to change that part?

Answer (score 2):

First thing, to avoid repeating code, is to extract it to a method:

```
private static int compute(int a, int b) {
    return (a*(a+1)*(2*a+1)/6-((a+1)*a/2)*(a+b)+(a+1)*a*b);
}
```

Now you want `b` to be the biggest of the two numbers, and `a` to be the other one. Instead of swapping them, you could use `Math.max` and `Math.min`:

```
a = sc.nextInt() - 1;
b = sc.nextInt() - 1;

System.out.println(compute(Math.min(a, b), Math.max(a, b));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
int k = Math.max(a, b)
a = Math.min(a, b);
b = k
```

After this piece of code, `b` will be the greater between the original `a` and `b`, while `a` will be the smaller, thus removing the need for the `if/else`.

Comment: Why do you need 'k' there?

Comment: Whenever you swap two variables, you need a temp variable to hold one of the two.

Comment: Writing `a = Math.min(a, b); b = Math.max(a, b)` would be wrong, because if `b` is less than `a`, then `a` becomes `b` and then `b` becomes the max between `b` and `b`. So you have two copies of `b`.

Comment: no, you don't necessarily need a temp variable for swapping int variables. But yes, your approach does :-P.